# How does this background css property work?

Tags: css

```
background: linear-gradient(top, #56B870 0%, #a5c956 100%) ;
```

I'm unfamiliar with the syntax, and the term `linear-gradient`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: I could not understand the difference between using px value and % value. I tried it myself but the didn't get satisfy-able result, because the color that had less percentage value covers higher area. I thought I could get some help from here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It does as it says and creates a linear gradient from one colour to the next.

```
linear-gradient(90deg, red 0px, green 10px, blue 20px);
```

This creates a linear gradient with the angle of 90 degrees. It starts as red, and over 10px will fade to green. It will then fade to blue over the next 10px.

It will remain blue for the rest of the elements width, however if you use repeating-linear-gradient it will reset it to red and repeat. You can add as many colours as you want to it, its pretty fun to mess about with!

Comment: OK I get it, but it isn't covering the whole background what can I do with that?

Comment: It basically sets the background to be a gradient of colours. Its just like:
`background: red;`
only instead of it being a red background, it fades between different colours. The intervals of it fading are specified by you, eg 35% for it to fully fade by 35% of the elements length. Does that help?